# Layout not showing properly on different devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have created an app in which I take linear layout and put 2 cardview inside it. The layout looks perfect on my 1080p device but it is not showing properly on devices with lower resolution.
Here are the screenshots of the app with some content missing on lower resolution device. I have used sp and dp for text and margins but still the problem. Is there anything I am missing?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2dp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/time_table"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/purple"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="75dp"
                        android:layout_height="75dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_time_table_black_24dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:text="Time Table"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:text="Check your time table here.."/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: With full resolution]

[image: with Low resolution]

Comment: If your layout is not that restricted in size and you want to make it occupy the space available to it, I don't recommend using fixed sizes. I recommend using constraintlayout too.

Comment: Could you show me your XML code. ?

Comment: @DPrince Okay..

Comment: @rmanalo i will try with constraint layout

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: are you use grid layout ? if no then are you use custom layout for all card ?

Comment: @DevAndro can u try my answer

Answer (score 0):

the above answer will slove your problem
But if you do not want to use `constraint layout`  and use other layout like `relative` or `linear` layout then i would recommend using multiple dimen file for this
[image: image 1]

it will create folders with the same name
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

> **Your Solution is here :**

In this case you can use layout_weight for maintain layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/time_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Time Table"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Check your time table here.."
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

imagview,textview need image and text can change it should work

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#123455"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Time Table"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Check your time table here.."
                    android:textColor="#fff" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#123455"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Time Table"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Check your time table here.."
                    android:textColor="#fff" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#123455"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Time Table"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Check your time table here.."
                    android:textColor="#fff" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#123455"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Time Table"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Check your time table here.."
                    android:textColor="#fff" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as I thought, you were using fixed sizes for your views. To make your layout scale naturally regardless of device screen size, as much as possible, use `match_parent` or `wrap_content`. Only `imageviews` are the things that I most of the time put fixed sizes to prevent the image to be stretched.

Use `constraintlayout` as much as possible. It's best layout to date. I don't use `relativelayout` anymore. If you need to make 2 side-by-side views to have identical sizes, a `tablerow` is enough. I don't thinks it's the best thing to do because it's not the flat layout google wants as to do but that's the only thing I know right now.

For the `cardviews`, you could put them on a `tablerow`. Set the `tablerow`'s `weightSum` to 2 then set the `cardview`'s `layoutWeight` to 1.

For the `padding`, use a standard size for it. I mostly use `8dp` for any padding I need. Also, if you really like designing or want to improve your knowledge about designing for android(please use the design editor, it'll make your life easier when using `constraintlayout`), read [this](https://material.io/). I don't apply everything in there because I don't know how to do them but it's nice to know a thing or 2 from that.

This is how I'm gonna do your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#910FF5">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Time Table"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Check your time table here"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#910FF5">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Time Table"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Check your time table here"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </TableRow>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As I've said, I don't know how to make this follow the flat layout guidelines of google. If someone knows how, please feel free to edit my answer. For my own good too.

Answer (score -1):

try using structure like this (use image element instead of textview  as your requirement is must use layout_weight attr):-

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ediv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_p"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white_p"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:text="@string/ftxt"
                android:textColor="@color/black"

                />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/ebar"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="92dp">

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ctxt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white_p"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/c_txt"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also if you want  your app layout  to be  independent  of device pixel then use constraint_layout as much as you can,and also try using 'sp' instead 'dp' for txt sizes.